# Qt scaling global environment variable not working consistently

Tags: environment-variables, xfce, resolution

I'm encountering one of those issues that happen inconsistently and are thus difficult to replicate, even for me.

I've a 4K (3840x2160) screen and I'm thus using HiDPI scaling whenever possible, with a factor of 2. However, since I'm running a custom setup combining Xfce (for the panel, settings and session manager) with bspwm (tiling window manager) and picom (compton's spiritual successor as a compositor), I normally have to get my hands a little dirty to scale Qt applications. Xfce settings only control GTK applications.

To enable Qt scaling, I normally follow [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#Qt_5), adding `export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2` in my `.bashrc` or trying the alternatives (`QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR`, `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS`) until it works. And work it did when I was running Ubuntu 20.04.

However, since I migrated to Debian 11 "Bullseye", Qt scaling is now inconsistent on a session basis. When it works, it works just fine, for every application. But other times, it doesn't work at all. It seems like I have to reboot until I get working. And it's like a coin-flip, both outcomes appear relatively frequently.

As a workaround, I can specify the environment variable locally, upon launching the application, instead of having it run globally. For example, `env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 qpdfview` does launch qpdfview with appropriate scaling.

This is of course not convenient and I'd rather have the global environment variable, defined in `.bashrc`, behave as it should. I've also tried creating a `.bash_profile` instead, by the way, but it didn't improve the situation.

So, what's going on? I'm suspecting troubles with starting order. Even when I don't get my scaling, `printenv` shows that `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` (or any alternative) is listed... so it's there, but something must be messing with it. I'm mentioning starting order as my (admittedly unusual) setup is apparently sensitive to which processes are (or not) already running; sometimes (rarely though), I'm booting to a messed up panel and windows that can't take up more than a quarter of the screen. So I just reboot and it's fine.

Anyway, I'd appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: problem solved! Lightdm was the perpetrator. As explained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#Environment_variables), `.bashrc` and related files aren't sourced when logging in from lightdm, since the display isn't launched by the shell. Lightdm does parse a few files for starting scripts and this is where you can store environment variables. Their exact name may depend on the distro. Archwiki says `~/.xprofile`, but [on Debian](https://itectec.com/unixlinux/bash-cant-export-environment-variables-on-x-session-start/) you'd use `~/.xsessionrc`.

So, I created `~/.xsessionrc` containing `export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2` and now it works.